# Where to find Oracle Time Zone regionids?

Tags: oracle, plsql, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

The Oracle built-in-procedure *dbms_utility.get_tz_transitions* is defined as

```
DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TZ_TRANSITIONS( 
   regionid      IN     NUMBER,
   transitions   OUT    MAXRAW);
```

and returns time zone transitions by regionid.

But: Where are the regionids defined/documented?
I.e. what's the regionid of Europe/Berlin - or any of the tzname-values in v$timezone_names?

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

As a time zone is a region of the globe that observes a uniform standard time for legal, commercial and social purposes and tend to follow the boundaries of countries and their subdivisions, Oracle only relates those standard values in a view for programming purposes. Think of it as a metadata table, regarding V$TIME_ZONES.

https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/

**The region id is retrieved from the timezone.dat file**, but at the end the procedure you mention outputs a raw.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on

DECLARE
 r RAW(22);
BEGIN
  dbms_utility.get_tz_transitions(10, r);
  dbms_output.put_line(r);

  dbms_utility.get_tz_transitions(12, r);
  dbms_output.put_line(r);
END;
/SQL> SQL>   2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
01766401010101011A3C00
0176640101010101183C00

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

The Oracle Database time zone files contain the valid time zone names. The following information is also included for each time zone:

- Offset from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)
- Transition times for Daylight Saving Time
- Abbreviations for standard time and Daylight Saving Time

Two time zone files are included in the Oracle Database home directory. The default time zone file is

- $ORACLE_HOME/oracore/zoneinfo/timezonelrg.dat, which contains all the
  time zones defined in the database.
- $ORACLE_HOME/oracore/zoneinfo/timezone.dat contains only the most
  commonly used time zones.

To enable the use of $ORACLE_HOME/oracore/zoneinfo/timezone.dat, perform the following steps:

- Shut down the database if it has been started.
- Set the ORA_TZFILE environment variable to  $ORACLE_HOME/oracore/zoneinfo/timezone.dat.
- Restart the database.

**UPDATE**

The file $ORACLE_HOME/oracore/zoneinfo/readme.txt might be the file you are looking for.

```
Timezones updated:
DSTVERSION TIME_ZONE_NAME FROM_YEAR TO_YEAR
26, Asia/Novokuznetsk, 1992, 1992
26, America/Santa_Isabel, 1800, 1800
DSTVERSION TIME_ZONE_NAME FROM_YEAR TO_YEAR
23, Africa/Ouagadougou, 1800,
23, Africa/Cairo, 2014, 2022
```

Perhaps the DSTVERSION refers to the region_id

Comment: Roberto, thanks for your explanation. In your example you provide values 10 and 12 as regionid to get_tz_transitions(), but what are the time zones of this values?. 
What im looking for are the region ids for timezone names or abbreviations, to get the transition data of given time zones.

Comment: Believe I tried to find that relationship in Oracle Support, and I could not find it. What are you using this package ? you cannot achieve the same with the Time Zone SQL functions ? just asking

Comment: A java guy asked me to help with this. Not sure why they need to know this - maybe some jdbc things. He showed me some java code where get_tz_transitions() is used to get the raw-value and interpret it. This is used to convert Java timezone objects to valid oracle timestamp with timezone values. To support more time zones they need to know the region ids. Thanks for your research.

Comment: @oratom , I think the info you are looking for might be in this file: $ORACLE_HOME/oracore/zoneinfo/readme.txt

Comment: Ok, I will check this tomorrow.

Comment: The file $ORACLE_HOME/oracore/zoneinfo/readme.txt appears to Oracle's implementation of the [IANA timezone database](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tz-link.html) (aka Olson database). This database seems to be the "standard" for timezone and DST implementations by companies and governments. The column DSTVERSION apparently referencing the timezone DST history file. I.E "26, Asia/Novokuznetsk..." referencing the file "timezlrg_26.dat".

Comment: @Belayer, I think so too. Oracle calls the timezone updates dstv<nn>. DSTVERSION seems to be exactly this version number. Unfortunately not what I am looking for.

Comment: It was worth a try. Actually I was so curious that I raised a question to Support to get an answer. I will post it as soon as I get it

Answer (score 0):

My completely random guess is

```
regionid= (zoneidbyte1-128)*64 + (zoneidbyte2/4)
```

You can find out `zoneidbyte1` and `zoneidbyte2` from a `timestamp with time zone` field with function `dump`: they are the last two bytes of data. For example *Europe/Kiev* is `id1=134,id2=96`

Mind you, it isn't documented anywhere, so even if it were true, it can be changed without notice.